# Rails validate a field value unless another field has a value

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails form with `f.association :employee` and `f.association :statuscode`

It happens that the first statuscode = "Not Assigned"  and the employee field is assigning an employee.

So, I the user enters an associated employee, I want the statuscode to be greater than 1.

I tried this:

```
  validates :statuscode_id, :numericality => { :greater_than => 1 }, :unless => :employee_id.blank?
```

But, I get:

```
undefined method `validate' for false:FalseClass
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using lambda

```
validates :statuscode_id, :numericality => { :greater_than => 1 }, :unless => lambda { |o| o.employee_id.blank? }
```

Comment: Thanks - I like this method.

Comment: Could you please explain why is lambda needed here?

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for something like this:

```
validates :statuscode_id, :numericality => { :greater_than => 1 }, :if => :employee_id_present?

private

def employee_id_present?
   employee_id.present?
end
```

... or any other the 2 other unique ways people said of doing this. :)